# How could Biff vividly remember the date within 30 years?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-ii

In *Back to the Future Part II*, in 1985A Marty asks Biff about the sports almanac. Not only does Biff remembers the exact date when he got the book - November 12, 1955 - but also tells Marty that he had his car fixed that day.

Why would Biff remember the exact date of receiving the almanac? I think it was not as relevant as the day when he won his first million in 1958. He could just say "it happened about 30 years ago".

I don't remember the exact dates of important events in my life that happened even 10 years ago. Is it possible to remember what happened 30 years ago? Can some of you guys really remember that far (I mean exact events of the day)?

Comment: We often remember significant dates, such as birthdays and anniversarys. Sure, we celebrate those a lot more frequently, but nothing says that Biff did not celebrate the anniversary of the day he met his future self and got given a magical book that led to him becoming a millionaire.

Comment: I think I would remember the day some crazy old man shoved a book in my hands and told me to place bets based on the information contained within.  Especially if that old man bore a striking resemblance to myself and *double especially* when *it started working when I tried it.*

Comment: With such a life and worldview-altering event, I don't think it is a huge leap of faith to believe that some people will remember the exact date.

Comment: Is any of the answers _acceptable_ to you?

Answer (score 4):

I can remember the exact date of some events in my life.

For example, I remember reading a book about the battle of Rourke's drift and noticing that the present date was the 100th anniversary of the battle, January 22 1979.

Answer (score 4):

> Marty McFly: That's right, Doc. November 12, 1955.
> Doc: Unbelievable, that old Biff could have chosen that particular date. It could mean that that point in time inherently contains some sort of cosmic significance. Almost as if it were the temporal junction point for the entire space-time continuum. On the other hand, it could just be an amazing coincidence.

Not only did Biff from alternate 1985 (1985A-Biff) remember that date, but [Biff from 2015 did too](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/160358/19561).

*Before* 1955-Biff had met 2015-Biff, it had already been a memorable day for Biff — but not in a good way. Until that day, Biff was the top dog at school. He had a gang following his leadership, he had his eyes set on Lorraine Baines and didn't know that neither in the original nor in the revised (after *Back to the Future I*) timeline she would fall for him.

Then George McFly — the school's nerdy wimp — stands up to him, knocks him out, and it all goes downhill for him from there. So 2015-Biff surely had a reason to remember that date.

---

Now 1985A-Biff was the first Biff that *didn't* experience that downfall, but still had very good reasons to remember that faithful night, because it had been an even weirder day for him.
He was still knocked out by the school nerd, George McFly, but besides that, he met a mysterious old man who gave him *Gray's Sports Almanac*. That was the beginning of his way to the top, to riches. Then that man also told him to watch out for a kid and a scientist coming for it.

> 2015-Biff: And don't tell anyone about it either. Oh, and there's one more thing. (Biffs leave the garage, conversation trails off) One day, a kid, or a crazy wild-eyed scientist who claims to be a scientist is gonna come around asking about that book...

So by all means, it is a memorable date, one that Biff surely would remember.

---

Comment: Some people have better memory than others. It could be the writers wanted Biff Tannen to have really good memory recall for the sake of his character’s deeds

Comment: The day Biff got the almanac (an important day for him) coincides with the day the clock tower was struck by lightning- a memorable day dor many people in town.  So Biff has two reasons to remember it - and every time someone mentions Clock Tower day (like a newspaper might on an anniversary) it reinforces Biff's memory of Almanac day

Answer (score 1):

As a gambler, Biff remembers the date of his first big win very well. He also has to remember the chain of events that made the win possible. Also he remembers that it happened right after his epic fail with the manure truck. Finally, the old man Biff told his young self to remember these things very well: never lose the Almanac, never tell anyone of it, especially a crazy old scientist and a young boy.

I think this is enough to remember the day very well.

Answer (score 0):

When the old Biff gives the young Biff the Almanac, we can hear him telling the young Biff that one day a kid and a guy claiming to be a scientist will come looking for the book someday in the future.

At first the young Biff doesn't believe him, but after he makes his first big win and finds out that the results given in the Almanac are actually correct, he takes the things the old Biff tells him more seriously, and this gives him enough incentive to remember everything Biff told him as well as the exact date he got the map.

Answer (score -2):

Has everyone forgotten about the fact he got his car back on that day after Marty made him crash into manure.

HE LOVED HIS CAR! Only
Only he could start it.

And it was the date of the Enchantment Under The Sea Dance.

All of biffs series of events happen on that day.
No wonder he remembered it.
Plus cause old biff no longer existed after gaining himself the almanac he was on a new life course after a crossroad and your subconsious would be aware of that. I think so anyway.